# Chrome browser automatically closing just after 1 sec,, what would be the reason

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver      
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")      
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com")
```

just opens the chrome and closes automatically after 1 sec

what is the reason?  is this any error with code?

Comment: Try adding `input()` after the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `detach` option when initializing the chromedriver. Also, `executable_path` is deprecated now. `Service` should be used instead, as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

webdriver_service = Service('C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=webdriver_service)
```